# Kernel - mainline test vs. mainline build

Tags: kernel, updates

What is the difference between those two? Recently there are no "mainline build"s, only "mainline tests"s:
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

Is it OK to install test-s? Are they stable and ready for production?

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I have been asking the very same question myself & I haven't been able to get any useful or helpful answers to this situation. What I can say is that if you look carefully at all the "mainline test" versions they appear incomplete & if you look carefully they are accompanied with many failed error messages. On that basis my advise would be to steer well away from trying to install ANY of the mainline test builds. ONLY install those kernel's which are called mainline builds. Only Mainline builds are usually complete & in a condition that is reasonably safe to install. i.e. if in doubt NEVER install a test build, if in doubt don't do it. Hope that helps? Regards Ivan